# Retrieve Connected Rows in MySql

Tags: mysql, rows, article

I have the following table in MySql Database:

[image]

I need to find out all the connected rows, wherever, a **case_sno** is exists in the **club_case_sno** column.

For example if someone search for case_sno = 10, it should retrieve the following result:

[image]

I need sql query which do the above.

Answer (score 0):

May try:

```
SELECT * FORM tbl_sno WHERE (club_case_sno = 10 
OR case_sno IN 
 ( SELECT club_case_sno FROM tbl_sno WHERE case_sno = 10) 
OR club_case_sno IN 
 ( SELECT club_case_sno FROM tbl_sno WHERE case_sno = 10))
AND is_connected = 1
```

Comment: the query you provide can return the resultant record but there is an issue, what if i search for 795? it will return only two rows? while i need a recursive list of all the connected rows. in other words, if i search any of the value in the result set which returned by your query may be able to return all the connected rows from column to column.